# LinqtoExcel: Not able to use where clause to select a row data

Tags: excel, where-clause, linq-to-excel

I am using linqtoexcel for my automation project. This file contains different site URL and its credentails. If I use only one row I am able to login to that site. But if there are two rows then I am having problem in using where clause.

Please help if you can if you do not understood anything please ask question.

1. [My excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whKtK.png)
2. Below is my code.

   `string pathfile = @"..\..\Data.xlsx";
   string sheetName = "Login";
   var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathfile);
   var abc = from a in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName).AsEnumerable() where Row.Field<String>("ID").Trim() == "2" select a;
   PropertiesCollection.driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
   foreach (var a in abc)
   {
   PropertiesCollection.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(a["URL"]);
   }
   foreach (var a in abc)
   {
   objLogin.Login(a["uname"], a["paswd"]);
   }`

I know I am wrong as per my code. Also I know, I have an error in `Field<String>`

**Please guide what will the better way to use where clause in linqtoexcel.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help  a specific row as per you condition. You just have to make changes in where clause.

```
string pathfile = @"..\..\Data.xlsx";
string sheetName = "Login";
var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathfile);
var abc = from a in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName).AsEnumerable() 
          where a["ID"] == "2" 
          select a;
PropertiesCollection.driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
foreach (var a in abc)
{
PropertiesCollection.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(a["URL"]);
}
foreach (var a in abc)
{
objLogin.Login(a["uname"], a["paswd"]);
}
```